# How can I fetch git information on a cloudControl machine?

Tags: git, cloudcontrol

I am looking for a way to automatically fetch those information on a cloudControl container. So I wrote a little Symfony2 service that returns some git information, e.g. the commit hash

```
public function getCommitHash() {
    exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD', $output);
    $hash = implode(', ', $output);
    return $hash;
}
```

If I run this on my local machine, it returns the proper shortened commit hash. But if I push this to my cloudControl machine, the return is `null`. I manually connected to the machine and ran this command on the command line (in the `www` folder, that is where the repository is pushed into). That throws the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I am really confused, as I thought I simply push my whole repository (including the `.git` folder) onto the remote machine. Why do I get this error and how can I fetch the git information instead?

Comment: This should be executed from project root directory.

Comment: What is the project root directory (if not `www`)?

Comment: where '.git' folder exists, this is hidden folder. 
or from where you executed 'git clone' command, and then go to project and then execute

Comment: Might be that this is not pointed out enough in my question, but I am talking about a cloudControl PaaS here. So I don't ´git clone` manually, but I push a repository onto the remote PaaS machine. Hence the `#cloudcontrol` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the git version within your running container, you can use the environment variable `DEP_VERSION`. E.g.:

```php
<?php
echo 'This container is running git commit ' .$_ENV["DEP_VERSION"] . '.';
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, this helps - although I can't fetch tag or branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fetch the git info from inside a container, since the git repository is not initialized where the code is located.

All the code is located in a repository node. You can get the remote address by executing `cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME details`, it will have the following format: `ssh://APP_NAME@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git`.

Given this git address, you can add it as a remote to your local directory (`git remote add cctrl ssh://APP_NAME@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git`) and get all git information as you want.

Comment: I am looking for a way to automatically fetch those information on the remote machine. Fetching it from local doesn't help me. But thanks anyway!